# How to expand MessagesViewController to full screen?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making an iMessage extension and I want it to expand to full screen when the user begins to interact.

What is the API to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
self.requestPresentationStyle(.expanded)
```

*Some more helpful code*

```
if self.presentationStyle == .compact {
    self.requestPresentationStyle(.expanded)
} else {
    self.requestPresentationStyle(.compact)
}
```

*Note: These calls are made from inside the MessagesViewController class*

Comment: is it possible to make the MessageViewController expanded by default? I tried calling this from viewDidLoad() as well as willBecomeActive() but it didn't work.